# Why is there a space gap when setting the padding of a Dialog to (0,0,0,0)?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I added a `List` to a `Dialog`. I tried all the possibilities :

```
dialog.getContentPane().getSelectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
dialog.getContentPane().getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
dialog.getContentPane().getStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
list.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(Component.LEFT, 0, false);
list.getSelectedStyle().setPadding(Component.LEFT, 0, false);
list.getStyle().setPadding(Component.LEFT, 0, false);
```

but there is still a space gap at the left : the colored `Label` returned from  `getListFocusComponent` of the `List` renderer doesn't occupy all the `Dialog`'s horizontal space !

So how to make the `Label` of the `getListFocusComponent()` occupy all the `Dialog`'s horizontal space : left and right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the list margin to 0 as well. The best way to see which component is responsible is to assign them a line border so you can see which component contains the padding/margin. Notice that the margin resides **outside** of that border.